# Is it possible to append to an outside list form inside a function?

Tags: python, list

I'm defining a function that performs calculations and needs to return the answer and put that answer into a list. I'm eventually going to get the average of the list, among other things, but I'm just curious if I can put the calculation formulas inside the function, and have it append to a list that was defined outside of the function. The reason for that is that I have multiple calculation formulas, and have to create multiple functions. I've simplified its essence here:

```
def triangle_perimeter(x):
    perimeter = (x * 3)
    
perimeters = []
x = input("Input a number: ")
triangle_perimeter(x)
perimeters.append(perimeter)
print(perimeters)
```

Comment: You should do this by passing the list into the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` a value from your function and pass that to your `append()` call.

You will also need to cast your `input()` as `int()` as it normally stores a `string`.

```
def triangle_perimeter(x):
  ## Return value from function ##
  return x * 3
    
perimeters = []
x = int(input("Input a number: "))

## Call append, appending the returned value from function ##
perimeters.append(triangle_perimeter(x))
print(perimeters)
```